# Generic Object remapping function with proper return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So basically I have data coming in from another via a post request in a large object. I need to pull out certain fields and put them in more specific objects with some of their fields remapped to then be inserted into a database.

I have this working in a non generic way, but I would like to have a more generic, but still completely type safe function.

This is a pared down version of the code as far as I have it right now.

```
import type { O } from 'ts-toolbelt';

const userFields = {
  accountFirstName: 'firstName',
  accountLastName: 'lastName',
  email: 'email',
  cellphone: 'cellPhone',
  city: 'city',
  state: 'state',
  street: 'street',
  zip: 'zip',
} as const;


const playerFields = {
  playerId: 'sc_id',
  playerFirstName: 'firstName',
  playerLastName: 'lastName',
  sizingJersey: 'jerseySize',
  sizingShorts: 'shortSize',
} as const;

const allFields = {
    ...userFields,
    ...playerFields
}

type EventData = typeof allFields;
type InvertedRecord<R extends { [P in keyof R]: R[P]; }> = Record<keyof O.Invert<R>, string>;

type UserRecord = InvertedRecord<typeof userFields>

function objectKeys<Obj> (obj: Obj): (keyof Obj)[] {
  return Object.keys(obj) as (keyof Obj)[];
};

// take just the user fields from the full data object and put them into a new object 
const extractUser = (data: EventData) => {
  const user: Partial<UserRecord> = {};
  objectKeys(userFields).forEach((field) => {
    user[allFields[field]] = data[field];
  });
  return user as UserRecord;
};

// A more generic extract function that takes the list of fields and the data object and extracts the fields into a new object
function genericExtract <T>(fields: T, data: EventData): T {
  const obj: Partial<T> = {};
  objectKeys(userFields).forEach((field) => {
    obj[allFields[field]] = data[field]; // <--- obj's type doesn't get properly inferred so the assignment is not compatible
  });
  return obj as T;
}
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nA8nAvnAMyghDgHIYBnAWhgggBsAjFBmMgbgCguBjCAHaV4AV0oooAMWCsAJpTgBeDFzhwAhr34iBMaVGEA5dSBQAucgWAGYx02QA0qjVog6YAGXVGT58g29bX0dnFBB1YAYLMjCIhhC1XlYGMAALQT8yJIYGAAV0gRQEuF5gJGjSpGLhdRhMmrrqmCgUFBho4Ra24oAvYDBovrAQ-G8SwWFuHn4heDAAxAlpOQVldGd59UWoAElZDt4AfWBZYs3t-R9TaKsbOyKnNXOJLyvMgLfq4D6BAHMAKQk4kQ0QAVkCUIgAMrfB7OSjfYB-KHpWCUDqomAwnpw0YKGaTaYTeDqHLLBjyJQqNRqAB09LESxkFMojxp9NpzykzPkXFwPCQqDgAFEAG4oXQAEVq6ipgpQEAIGjJPMo3HlcB2AnFsBQsgASih%20FBZAAefVwFAADzqAkpmAA2rk4Ei4ABrSGKuD6gC6Fn1Tp9HDwAD4qYbjWaPYgvVhaVqdTBzSGHHBOkjfiGphqAKriKAR6CyKkJiR1A1Goum%20VexnclYhngEHS8GDAQRwCBMcGtgDSkMopqw3bDAAou6CLMPQQBKCyj6Ox7szh0%206lwFowERQATYbtGmC06OUcfLjQKBeepXTldBvlTAD0D4Q6g9cFBYngMFSaDrhFVhDEKQ35oM2ORwLIMqdvurYaHacBgCIX4-qQSJ0BocCFAA7tBPbwHwxKWjaUCaDAeYSFSo6QTA6gWGKEowNKNEzkoYbrIkhF1hYuTqLAwCkqa5EFpWJphmsuDcGoE4Hv2iAnnW5LyDOtIENAwqaKko6jlYcgsYobHOGodYOqSDCKZQDo6RSPprso1HqJZPJ3mouAzpJG5tNuu5-mMQmFia3ASTwT5wAAgnAIDQGgvwShIwC8ERzSkYQLZth2361C%20HoKCBcAMMAwidkqVmUuo8G5fZuEHnBxbWklrY5T%20-4rC6ugQBh2FVa2XDNgIrbtruMWFFA8XCsRyWmgAKiG2mqhYk2pvZdHilKMpznAk3rgS8ATtxvFtgJ01UugQVSTBMCyfJ%20bmcpqlQOpvCabNumseuZ2giZKorI5cg2VS9k-dZwYhaa1BgxtqQFS6CiUKgpRWLwpmIHAWE-i0CBNQVlAiGg%20UoJQziue5m5ebh54bYFQA) for more context on the issue hat hand..

[Second Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nA8nAvnAMyghDgHIYBnAWhgggBsAjFBmMgbgCguBjCAHaV4AV0oooAMWCsAJpTgBeDFzhwAhr34iBMaVGEA5dSBQAucgWAGYx02QA0qjVog6YAGXVGT58g29bX0dnFBB1YAYLMjCIhhC1XlYGMAALQT8yJIYGAAV0gRQEuF5gJGjSpGLhdRhMmrrqmCgUFBho4Ra24oAvYDBovrAQ-G8SwWFuHn4heDAAxAlpOQVldGd59UWpax9TaKsbOyKnNU3trz3MgKvq4D6BAHMAKQlxRGiAKzeURABle4nZyUe7AJ5-dKwSgdSEwAE9IGjBQzSbTCbwdQ5ZYMeRKFRqNQAOmJYiWMhxlFOBOJhPOZJWXFwPCQqDgAFEAG4oXQAEVq6jxLJQEAIGix5Pk3CFcAAkgIubAULIAEoofhQWQAHmVcBQAA86gJcZgANq5OBguAAa1+IrgyoAuhZlWaHRw8AA+PGq9Vam2IO1YQlyhUwbUehxwTpgx4eqbSgCq4igPugsjxIYkdRVarTmqFdtJOxWHp4BB0vBgwEEcAgTG+lYA0r9KJqsPWvQAKOufCztz4ASgsnf9gfrA5NDvxcBaMBEUAE2HrapghP9lG7440ChHttF-YnbsZUwA9CeEOobXBPmJ4DBUmgi4QJQoiCQEA-CCIcnBZPza8ulYaEacBgCId4PqQYJ0BocCFAA7gBDbwHw6K6gaUCaDASYSHinZ-jA6gWJy3IwHyhEDkoXrrIkaFFhYuTqLAwCYpqOEprmGpemsuDcGoPYrs2iAbkW2LyAOhIENAbKaKknadlYciUYo1HOGoRYmpiDBiZQJqKTiDpTsoBHqHpEpHmouADnxM5tPOi5PmM7Gphq3C8cyyBoAAapiIgoK2AAq3FwAFJqjqKAVHlwZ5wAAgnAIDQGgjzchIwC8OhzRYV+AiVtWi73rUF42go95oAwwDCLWor6bi6ggWVv7-gJQH1em+pZZWpWfrVCjQRAsEIUhK5cOWuVVjWKWFFA6Vshh2WagFmXcriLlaj5DB+a2BailpOkRlGzQxh6HoKS+FgBZGJnEVyvL8kOIXTii8A9gxTFVqxQV4ug7n8YBMBCRuvUSVJUAybwclnUpVHTn9nyaeKKxmXIhl4iZyMGe6MWatQuMhaklUWgolCoKUVi8FpiBwPBD4tB+aCVZQflwBV-nOFZNmzvZSHbiFblorM7J6iY8woCRd2Ed9ziaNouj6Fc0TPBAqQCMUMtuLolxBPs5A8hAQJqLEkRfMrAgAAKyPrhL8CAxTZHkBSZAArC7ABs7sAOxex7dtlB85B-PVcA8jIjwQE0tSZAAwrFTRdO05AALIRIufyrr0-TRAAnDnOfFHSOxHL4By7NrBugQsEha8c0Q3GXdwPC8Pz+2Q3wGL88LlyCjcQtAVAwn3ncjALVXsf2eJTWlvBzZ1MCdqJL6RnNIsMGLt1kfd8aeXACaCp5dpj-Wp7nomUsxQSz5Fzr0ZPNw58EnXNeHTNt-ReeF9G1Ez8xnf78Evb+QMgWBvo8X+F8Sh+2AUdV+981AND8CAsBF9OitATogt+4ChhQJfqAjBF827vE7tgn+eCCSUFhEQ7+MDzxMlQkIRgKBCQMAgI8Tsh9PiSVLscAcQA)

Answer (score 1):

First, a simple type to get the values of an object type:

```
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];
```

The problem is that `T` in `genericExtract` is not constrained. That means `allFields[field]` is not necessarily a key of `T`, which is why you get an error.

To solve this, add a constraint to `T`:

```
function genericExtract <T extends Record<Values<typeof allFields>, unknown>>(fields: T, data: EventData): T {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nA8nAvnAMyghDgHIYBnAWhgggBsAjFBmMgbgCguBjCAHaV4AV0oooAMWCsAJpTgBeDFzhwAhr34iBMaVGEA5dSBQAucgWAGYx02QA0qjVog6YAGXVGT58g29bX0dnFBB1YAYLMjCIhhC1XlYGMAALQT8yJIYGAAV0gRQEuF5gJGjSpGLhdRhMmrrqmCgUFBho4Ra24oAvYDBovrAQ-G8SwWFuHn4heDAAxAlpOQVldGd59UWoAElZDt4AfWBZYs3t-R9TaKsbOyKnNXOJLyvMgLfq4D6BAHMAKQk4kQ0QAVkCUIgAMrfB7OSjfYB-KHpWCUDqomAwnpw0YKGaTaYTeDqHLLBjyJQqNRqAB09LESxkFMojxp9NpzykzPkXFwPCQqDgAFEAG4oXQAEVq6ipgpQEAIGjJPMo3HlcB2AnFsBQsgASih+FBZAAefVwFAADzqAkpmAA2rk4Ei4ABrSGKuD6gC6Fn1Tp9HDwAD4qYbjWaPYgvVhaVqdTBzSGHHBOkjfiGphqAKriKAR6CyKkJiR1A1Goum+VexnclYhngEHS8GDAQRwCBMcGtgDSkMopqw3bDAAou6CLMPQQBKCyj6Ox7szh0+6lwFowERQATYbtGmC06OUcfLjQKBeepXTldBvlTAD0D4Q6g9cFBYngMFSaDrhFVhDEKQ35oM2ORwLIMqdvurYaHacBgCIX4-qQSJ0BocCFAA7tBPbwHwxKWjaUCaDAeYSFSo6QTA6gWGKEowNKNEzkoYbrIkhF1hYuTqLAwCkqa5EFpWJphmsuDcGoE4Hv2iAnnW5LyDOtIENAwqaKko6jlYcgsYobHOGodYOqSDCKZQDo6RSPprso1HqJZPJ3mouAzpJG5tNuu5-mMQmFia3ASQKyBoAAaqSIgoIOAAqYlwNFDqLkq0V3lwT5wAAgnAIDQGgvwShIwC8ERzSkYQLZth2361C+HoKCBcAMMAwidkqVmUuo8ENfZuEHnBxbWqVrb1T+-4rC6ugQBh2G9a2XDNgIrbtru+WFFARXCsRZWmtFJUSpS-lmuFDCRYONZKqZ5kpnAOhugIEBYQIIYhtpqoWNFqb2XR4pSjKc7xeuBLwBO3G8W2AmxVS6BBVJMEwLJ8n5uZymqVA6m8Jpr26ax66w6CJkqisjlyDZVL2cT1nBulprULT8WpM1LoKJQqClFYvCmYgcBYT+LQIKNzWUJFjUyJQziue5m5ebh57xYFQA)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. This got me extremely close, it just doesn't like the type of the first parameter and my pleb brain can't understand why lol.. I added a second playground link showing usage with the new type error.